# ORDER BY with characters and numeric

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, varchar

I have the following values in my columns and I need to order them on the basis of their name.Datatype of the column is VARCHAR2 (25 BYTE).My data is

```
 Oracle 10g, Oracle 9i, Oracle 11g
```

When I user ORDER BY Name, I got result in the order

```
    Oracle 10g
    Oracle 11g
    Oracle 9i
```

What can I do to get the data in order as shown below

```
    Oracle 9i
    Oracle 10g
    Oracle 11g
```

Comment: Jus use ORDER BY Name ASC.

Comment: Which datatype you are using ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clearly state what the "correct order" is. I think it's something along the lines of sorting textually until digits are encountered, then collecting adjacent digits, converting those to a number and continuing the sort numerically. But it quickly gets quite complex to specify (e.g. if you need to revert to a textual sort after the numbers are considered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* order based on a number in string */
SELECT  str
FROM
(
        SELECT 'Oracle 10g' str FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Oracle 11g'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Oracle 9i'      FROM DUAL
)
ORDER   BY
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '\D'))

/* result */
Oracle 9i
Oracle 10g
Oracle 11g
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Works as expected

Here we have alpha numeric characters. please use `substring` function.

> select column_name from table_name order by **SUBSTRING**(name,0,8)

Use ascending or descending as per your requirement.

Note: 8 is the length, because Oracle and Space is the common characters between them.

Comment: Data in the above blog is only applicable if the first part of the string is integer(always). In my case the first is always alphabet.

Comment: @ Joshi Kumar , Sorry for the delay. The above query didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

Comment: Did you try it before posting your answer? How it is helps OP get the correct order by Oracle version number (9->10->11)?

Comment: This query results in the order    Oracle 9i
                                   Oracle 11g
                                   Oracle 10g